# Dynamic multidimensional array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble writing this program. I want to define a 2-D array, let's call it Cube. The dimensions of the array should be dependent upon an input called Number. Such that, the dimensions of the array Cube should be Cube(0 to Number, 0 to Number).

I would like Cube(0,0) to be set to another input, Starter. From here, I would like the rest of the array to be calculated from this starting point. The whole top row should be calculated as the previous number multiplied by input X. So

```
Cube(1,0) = Cube(0,0)*X
Cube(2,0) = Cube(1,0)*X
Cube(3,0) = Cube(2,0)*X
And so on.
```

Starting with the 2nd row, the rest of the array should be calculated by multiplying the number above and to the left by another input Y. For example:

```
Cube(1,1) = Cube(0,0)*Y
Cube(2,1) = Cube(1,0)*Y
Cube(2,2) = Cube(1,1)*Y
Cube(3,1) = Cube(2,0)*Y
And so on...
```

Once all the values are defined, I would like to change the values of any numbers below input Z to 500. For example, `if Cube(56,42)< Z`, then the value of Cube(56,42) will be changed to equal 500.

Finally, I want to work back from the right-most column to get back to the starting point of Cube(0,0). If the array's dimensions ended at 100, then:

```
If Cube(99,0)=500, then keep it as 500, 
Else Cube(99,0)=Cube(100,0)*A + Cube(100,1)*B
```

For the sake of repetition:

```
If Cube(68,54)=500, then keep it as 500,
Else Cube(68,54)=Cube(69,54)*A + Cube(69,55)*B
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide your code and people can help you fix problems in your code. No one will write the code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i followed your logic correctly:

```
Public Sub CubeArray()
Dim Cube()      As Double, _
    i           As Long, _
    j           As Long, _
    X           As Double, _
    Y           As Double, _
    Z           As Double, _
    A           As Double, _
    B           As Double

Const CubeSize = 10 'Change this value to change your array size
ReDim Cube(0 To CubeSize, 0 To CubeSize) As Double
Cube(0, 0) = InputBox("What would you like the first value of the array to be?")
X = InputBox("X =")
Y = InputBox("Y =")
Z = InputBox("Z =")
A = InputBox("A =")
B = InputBox("B =")
For i = 1 To UBound(Cube)
    Cube(i, 0) = Cube(i - 1, 0) * X
    For j = 1 To UBound(Cube)
        Cube(i, j) = Application.Max(Cube(i - 1, j - 1) * Y, Z)
    Next j
Next i
For i = UBound(Cube) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For j = 0 To UBound(Cube) - 1
        If Cube(i, j) <> Z Then
            Cube(i, j) = Cube(i + 1, j) * A + Cube(i + 1, j + 1) * B
        End If
    Next j
Next i
MsgBox Cube(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this possibly?

```
Sub demo()
    Const n As Long = 10

    Range("A1").Resize(n + 1, n + 1).Value = DaCube(n, 1, 2, 3)
End Sub

Function DaCube(n As Long, a As Double, x As Double, y As Double) As Double()
    Dim adCube() As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    ReDim adCube(0 To n, 0 To n)
    adCube(0, 0) = a

    For i = 1 To n
        adCube(i, 0) = adCube(i - 1, 0) * x

        For j = 1 To n
            adCube(i, j) = adCube(i - 1, j - 1) * y
        Next j
    Next i

    DaCube = adCube
End Function
```